# Strongswan - Is it possible to “include” other ipsec.conf files that have their own “conn %default” settings

Tags: linux, vpn, ipsec, strongswan

I'm looking for some help or suggestions with strongswan

I work with an obscene amount of VPNs with different types and configurations, ikev1( I know, I know, above my paygrade and not my decision),ikev2, main mode, aggressive, PSKs, Certs etc

I'm just looking for a way to better manage them and try to encourage some consistency and I'm wondering if I could create separate ipsec.conf files for each e.g.

ipsec.conf.ikev1, ipsec.conf.ikev2, ipsec.conf.certs

I know you can "include" other .conf files within the main one, however id like each .conf file to contain their own "conn %default" so that the relevant and static settings for each type of configuration can just be defined under default and then we only need to specify the "right" settings e.g. right ID, right subnet etc.

I sense I already know the answer to this, but figured the good people of SO might offer some suggestions.

Cheers